# Magento can't create cache product images!

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Product cache folder is empty, seems like product images create failed. I have installed gd, and found logs below:

```
2014-12-04T01:22:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'imagecreatefromjpeg' not found or invalid function name  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2.php on line 61
2014-12-04T01:22:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2.php on line 376
2014-12-04T01:22:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'imagejpeg' not found or invalid function name  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2.php on line 167
```

Magento: 1.9.0
PHP: 5.6.0
Apache: 2.4.6
Mariadb: 5.5.37

Answer (score 7):

Function `imagecreatefromjpeg` is available only if PHP was compiled with GD support and have JPEG support enabled. According to the phpinfo() output JPEG support was not enabled in your GD library. If you have compiled PHP GD library yourself please make sure that `libjpeg` is installed and `--with-jpeg-dir` option is set before `--with-gd` option. Or ask your host to install PHP GD Library with JPEG support (so it is listed in `phpinfo()` output)

Comment: phpinfo() have showed below, so the PHP was complied with GD support, right?<br>
GD Support enabled<br>
GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)<br>
GIF Read Support enabled<br>
GIF Create Support enabled<br>
PNG Support enabled<br>
libPNG Version 1.5.13<br>
WBMP Support enabled<br>
XBM Support enabled<br>

Comment: Oh, sorry, bad text display!

Comment: According to the output of phpinfo() JPEG support is not listed there. I have updated the answer with details about libjpeg in GD.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the problem, I have rebuilt php with JPEG support, it's working now!

Comment: @DonghuaLau please accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: while i print phpinfo(); in GD libraries everthing is enable but still not get any update about .GIF file  .GIF image animation now working for me.