# JPG product images won't display but PNG will

Tags: product, product-images

A old client of mine has come to me because most of her product images have stopped being displayed on her site.

After some investigation it seems that if a product image is a png file, it displays, if it is a jpg it doesn't.

Jpgs that are part of the theme (e.g. the credit card symbols in the footer) are showing ok.

I've flushed the images cache.  The permissions on the media\catalog\product.. folders are set to 0777. The files are definitely on the server and the product page seems to be calling the correct file. I can't see anything wrong with the pathing.

I've deleted one and reuploaded the same image to the same product as both jpg and png, and only the png will load.

See this product for example:
http://www.justcardsdirect.com/happy-anniversary-no-verse.html

Can anyone suggest what I could try in order to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Are the right image libraries like Imagick and GD installed?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the image does not exist? The server returned a 404 for the image.

http://www.justcardsdirect.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/n/ann_140_400_2.jpg

Just saw Sander Mangel's comment.That might be the solution. If pngs are being cached, and jpegs, not, there might be a problem with GD.

See this:[Magento can't create cache product images!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46293/magento-cant-create-cache-product-images)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments. We had someone with more server knowledge than me, took a look and it was a caching issue apparently!